# How to make a Controller Function call from Views Template in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Rails and have a function in product_controller.rb

```
def detach
  @product.photo = nil
  @product.save
end
```

now I want to call this method from views file show.html.erb so the method get executed. How to do it ? I can see the 7 methods do get called through .find(params[id]) but that is also not clear to me.

Comment: Calls happens from controller to views but not from views to controllers. So then you don't need the calling, routes will do that for controller actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing as follow

```
<%= link_to 'detach_image', product_detach_path(@product) %>
```

I would suggest you to have a look at guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html.

you can do as follow,

you can use match

```
match '/update_profile', :to => 'users#update_profile'
```

or

```
resources :users do
  get 'update_profile', on: :member
end
```

and then you would definitely have method in your users controller

```
def update_profile
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  if @user.save
    redirect_to @user, notice: 'user updated successfully!'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Finally it worked :) couple of questions. 1. What is the difference between product_detach_path(@product) and just product_detach_path ? 2. What is this code doing "resources :products do
  member do
    get 'detach' # /products/:id/detach
  end
end"

Comment: :) simple man, you have to tell your method which thing you need to update, so we do `product_detach_path(@product)` plus i would suggest you to take tutorials from guides.rubyonrails.org . 2nd answer, it is just generating the route and telling the controller to expect product from the link (in your case) on which users click.

Accept my answer. :) thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add a route, something like this in `routes.rb`:

```
resources :products do
  member do
    get 'detach' # /products/:id/detach
  end
end
```

That will give you `detach_product_path(@product)` which you can use in your view. You'll probably also want a redirect in the detach method:

```
def detach
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @product.photo = nil

  if @product.save
    redirect_to @product, notice: 'Photo was detached!'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, do I need this "get '/detach' => 'products#detach', on: :member" under resources :products ? as while running rake routes, it is giving me error that incorrect syntax.

Comment: This is my current code in routes,"  resources :products do
     get 'detach' => "products#detach"
  end
" , the route that got created is - "product_detach GET    /products/:product_id/detach(.:format) products#detach" and I have put in show.html.erb file - "<%= link_to 'detach_image', product_detach_path %>" .. and I am getting Error "No route matches {:action=>"detach", :controller=>"products"}"

Comment: you don't need of " => 'products#detach' "

Comment: @MuhamamdAwais @Simon - I have got the routes correcct now and the show page is being shown but when I click on the "<%= link_to 'detach_image', detach_product_path %>" link, it is showing NoMethodError in ProductsController#detach undefined method `photo=' for nil:NilClass, the line with error is - " @product.photo = nil"

Comment: i have updated my answer please have a look and feel free to accept it. If it looks good

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the Simon answer. However, you are still facing the problem because you are not passing the product with the path:

```
<%= link_to 'detach_image', detach_product_path %>
```

You need to pass the product to the action:

```
<%= link_to 'detach_image', detach_product_path(@product) %>
```

Otherwise, the `Product.find(params[:id])` will not find any product, and the `@product` will get empty...

**Edit** to reply your questions:

1 - `product_detach_path` is a helper for the action `detach` in the controller `product`. There is also the `product_detach_url`, which does the same thing, but also includes the current host, port and path prefix. More details [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-url).
However, it does not pass any param, so `Product.find(params[:id])` cannot find the product. For this reason, you must specify what product are you trying to find. `@product` is defined in the `show` action, so it is available in your view, but you could send any other product for the `detach action`.... maybe the first one: `product_detach_path(Product.first)`

2 - the `resources :products` generates [seven default routes:](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) index, new, create, show, edit, update and destroy.
In order to add more routes to it, you can use `member` or `collection`. Basically, `member` will add a route to a product (products/1/detach), while `collection` will add a route to the controller, like index (products/detach). More information [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions).

I hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks, Finally it worked :) couple of questions. 1. What is the difference between product_detach_path(@product) and just product_detach_path ? 2. What is this code route code doing "resources :products do
  member do
    get 'detach' # /products/:id/detach
  end
end"

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it Gabriel